# how to print value once from array object when it has same value

Tags: php, laravel

hello i am fetching row from tables and showing them in view, but some rows has same value for cust_name field as i want to show then once...

my controller is

```
 $del = Prev_delivery::where('del_date', $date)
                        ->where('status', "0")
                        ->get();
 return view('kitchen.kitchen',['del'=> $del]);
```

and view is

```
foreach ($del as $value) {?>
        <tr id="">
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <button class="btn" value="{{$value->cust_id}}">{{$value->cust_name}}</button>
        </td>            
    </tr>
     <?php }
```

it is showing value 'Alex' two times as i want to print only once... how can i get it. Thank you.

Comment: use `array_unique($del)`

Comment: it is showing error as array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`groupBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset):

```
$del = Prev_delivery::where('del_date', $date)
                        ->where('status', "0")
                        ->groupBy('cust_name')
                        ->get();

return view('kitchen.kitchen',['del'=> $del]);
```